# BeautifulSoup navigation ignores specified path

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

It appears as though my `BeautifulSoup` parser ignores the path of the element I request and returns the first tag found that bears the name of the final element in the path regardless of the path up to that point.

XML:

```
<root>
    <firstcategory>
        <subcategory>
            <id>123</id>
            <name>SubcategX</name>
        </subcategory>
        <id>789</id>
        <name>Category1</name>
    </firstCategory>
</root>
```

`Python` code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

testXML = "<root><firstcategory><subcategory><id>123</id><name>SubcategX</name></subcategory><id>789</id><name>Category1</name></firstCategory></root>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(testXML)
#below should be 789
categID = soup.root.firstcategory.id
#this prints 123, which corresponds to the path root.firstcategory.subcategory.id, not root.firstcategory.id
print("categID = %s" % categID)
```

Why does BeautifulSoup simply find the first id tag in the hierarchy irrespective of the specified path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the dot syntax, BeautifulSoup is searching all ancestors recursively. It happens to find the subcategory `<id>` first.

To prevent recursion, you can do:

```
soup.firstcategory.find('id', recursive=False)
```

Here are the [docs for the recursive argument](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument).